# PHPで、演算子の前後にスペースを入れるかどうか、について言及しているコーディング規約はありますか？

Tags: php

`== 1` と `==1` が混在していたのでどちらかに統一したいのですが、PHPで演算子の前後にスペースを入れるかどうかについて言及している(参考になりそうな)コーディング規約はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サイトの名前や内容的に、おそらくこれが該当していそうです。

[PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)のページの中の以下の部分。

[6.2. Binary operators](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#62-binary-operators)

> All binary arithmetic, comparison, assignment, bitwise, logical, string, and type operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space:

> すべての二項算術、比較、代入、ビット単位、論理、文字列、および型の演算子は、前後に少なくとも 1 つのスペースを置く必要があります。